# create additional github account with ssh access

Tags: git, github, ssh

I've got my main github account with ssh access. It has keys and config looks like this

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

I've created new GitHubTest for experiment purposes. And I've created new `git` repository and generated ssh key.
So I modified my config file with additional lines

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com-GitHubTest
    User git
    IdentityFile D:/workTestProjects/git-test/id_rsa_present
```

But how to test it? When I do `ssh -T git@github.com` it shows hello message for my main account.

Comment: What is it you're actually wanting to test - as all you're testing above is basically how ssh auth works...? Is there an underlying question such as "how can I push code to github as two different users?" (implicitly answered below) or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hostname` part in the SSH config is the host you want to connect to, what you should do is :

```
Host github-test
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile D:/workTestProjects/git-test/id_rsa_present
```

And then you can test with :

```
ssh -T github-test
```